# How I can delete this space between tabbar and collectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uicollectionviewcell, collectionview

How I can delete this space between tabbar and collectionView?
I have a tabbar -> viewcontroller -> collection
this purple rect it is part of ViewController, but the problem that collection view has the same frame as vc.

[image]

Here log:

```
print("Frame.height:  collectionView ->\(collectionView.frame.height) ---  view \(view.frame.height)")
```

Terminal

```
  Frame.height:  collectionView -> 812.0 ---  view 625.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you changing the height of the standard tabbar?

If so, you're doing it in the wrong place, and the ViewController might compute its height before your change on the tabbar. Try modifying the height in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`.

Answer (score 0):

you probably need to adjust the bottom constraint of the collection view to be the top constraint of the tab bar